# Why I can't get object firebase from angular.js factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I have factory

```
    o.getUserWorkout = function (_id) {
        if (_id){
            $firebaseArray(DBC.getRef().child('workouts')
                    .orderByChild('userID')
                    .equalTo(DBC.getAuthRef().$getAuth().uid)
            ).$loaded()
                .then(function (x) {
                    console.log(x.$getRecord(_id))
                    return x.$getRecord(_id);
                });
        }
    };
```

and controller

```
function workoutController($scope, workoutFct, $state) {
    $scope.editUserWorkout = function (_id) {
        console.log(workoutFct.getUserWorkout(_id));
    };
}
```

Why do I get right value of object in

```
console.log(x.$getRecord(_id))
```

in console

```
Object {description: .......
```

but in controller

```
console.log(workoutFct.getUserWorkout(_id));
```

I get

```
undefined
```

Comment: try workoutFct.getUserWorkout(_id).then(function(id){ console.log(id); }); in your controller

Comment: please put the hole object that returned from  `console.log(x.$getRecord(_id))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your service returning promises so you need to use the .then to access the returned data

```
workoutFct.getUserWorkout(_id).then(function(id){ 
    console.log(id);
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
workoutFct.getUserWorkout(_id).$loaded().then(function (x) 
{
    console.log(x.$getRecord(_id)); 
});
```

Comment: I did like this
                workoutFct.getUserWorkout(_id)
                .$loaded()
                .then(function (x) {
                    console.log(x.$getRecord(_id));
                });